# Enable explicit Type indices in coqtop?

Tags: coq

In Coq there is a hierarchy of types each one denoting the type of the previous i.e. Type_0 : Type_1, Type_1 : Type_2 and so on. In `coqtop` however when I type `Check Type.` I get `Type : Type` which looks like a contradiction but is not since `Type` is implicitly indexed.

*Question:* How to enable explicit indexing of the Type universes?

Comment: You want to use `Set Printing Universes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer as @ejgallego mentioned above is to enable the printing of universe levels:

```
Coq < Set Printing Universes.
Coq < Check Type.
Type@{Top.1}
     : Type@{Top.1+1}
(* Top.1 |=  *)
```

Conceptually there is indeed a hierarchy of types which might be called `Type@{1}`, `Type@{2}`, etc. However, Coq actually maintains symbols for universe indices and relationships among them (universe constraints) rather than explicit numbers. The constraints are kept consistent so that it's always possible to assign some explicit number to every symbol in a consistent manner.

In the output above you can see that Coq has created a universe level `Top.1` for the `Type` inside the `Check Type.` command. Its type is always one level higher, which Coq does without another symbol with the expression `Top.1+1`. With `Set Printing Universes` a list of constraints is also output as a comment; in this case it gives the one symbol in the context `Top.1` and no constraints on the right hand side.

Coq maintains a global list of universe levels and constraints it has created so far. You can read a more thorough explanation of universe levels and constraints in CPDT: http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Universes.html.